# Not able to check 2nd checkbox. Getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (106, 655)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting WebDriverException while trying to select the 2nd checkbox in the list. I am able to select the 1st check box but on the 2nd time my code throwing exception. Please find the method that i am using and exception message below.
Note: Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

URL: https://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers-external-hard-drives?sort=plrty&q=Capacity_s%3A1%20TB%7C

```
public void capacitySelection(String capacity){
        WebDriverWait wd = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
        List<WebElement> cList = wd.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@data-name='Capacity_s']/div")));
        int i=1;
        for(WebElement we:cList){
            WebElement select= wd.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-name='Capacity_s']/div["+ i++ +"]/label")));
            if(select.getText().contains(capacity)){
                select.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

Exception Message:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (106, 655). Other element would receive the click: <label for="Capacity_s-3TB">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 86 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'Bishnu', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\Users\Bishnu\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11044_5076}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=54.0.2840.99, platform=WIN8, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 505ec9fb429bc6b9806edb52d75856f0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at in.prolearn.pages.HomePage.SecondCapacitySelection(HomePage.java:59)
    at in.prolearn.testcases.VerifySnapDealSelection.main(VerifySnapDealSelection.java:22)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use JavaScript instead

```
        WebElement product = new WebDriverWait(aDriverInstance, 5L).
                until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy(By.id("anID")));

        JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) aDriverInstance;
        jsExec.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", product);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(select).click().perform();
```

Try to click the element with Actions class. This will help you.

Comment: Now i am getting  org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException. Also u can see some Html changes once the 1st item is selected. please use the above url and try to select 1 TB and 2 TB capacity check box.

Comment: If you see some html changes after the 1st item is selected then you have to locate the second check box after your 1st selection. In your code, you have selected all the web elements and stored it in a list even before you choose the first check box and that is why you are getting StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: Hi Thanks for you valuable input. If you will see the above method i am calling from main() when i trying to select a checkbox. Each time we will call this method, it will select that particular checkbox only.So when I am calling the above method to select the 2nd checkbox, it will find the all web element and store in the variable one more time. If you have little time then you can open the above url and see if you can help me on the same. Thanks again

Comment: Hey Thanks for you help. Now i am able to resolve the issue. The issue was with sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

Use .isSelected() method before performing click on that element.